# Select list value change using jQuery but does not shows in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hy everyone,
I get a problem when changing select list option in jQuery,
everything is working fine outside this theme.
when I create the select list in this theme it is changing select list like.
theme name is developr

**My code :**

```
<select id="PackageID" name="PackageID" class="validate[required] withClearFunctions" style="width:200px" >
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">100 paper</option>
  <option value="2">500 paper</option>
</select>
```

**What I got after rander**

```
<span class="drop-down custom-scroll">
  <span class="selected">Please select</span>
  <span>100 paper</span>
  <span>500 paper</span>
  <div class="custom-vscrollbar" style="display: none;"><div></div></div>                           
</span>
```

when I change option in jQuery html changes but UI does not change.

**Code after selecting select list**

```
<span class="drop-down custom-scroll">
  <span>Please select</span>
  <span class="selected">100 paper</span>
  <span>500 paper</span>
  <div class="custom-vscrollbar" style="display: none;"><div>
</span>
```

Comment: are you using a plugin to render your select differently?

Comment: I solve this by evoking change event $('#PackageID').change();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem.
I just firing the change event using jQuery

```
$('#PackageID').change();
```

this event update UI.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to set option without a select drop down. See fiddle for the most terse/readable option

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcp6t7vb/)

Option 1:

```
$('#PackageID').val('2');
```

Option 2 - via index:

```
$('#PackageID :nth-child(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

Option 3 - via value:

```
$('#PackageID option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

All will update DOM and therefore render correctly.

Comment: thank you for your comment. but already tried all method, problem was value is changing but UI does not show change, I can see change in inspect elements,     but I solve the problem using firing change event for select list using         $('#PackageID').change();